# Aliasing and pointer-interconvertability

Tags: c++, pointer-aliasing, pointer-conversion

Given the following code:

```
struct Tag {};
struct X {
//    Tag t; // if not commented it shouldn't be pointer-interconvertible
    int k;
};

int fn(const X& x, int& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

The generated code is:

```
fn(X const&, int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 2
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

Here the compiler assumes aliasing.

If member `t` is not present, the types `X` and `int` are pointer-interconvertible. As so, the compiler must generate code as if the references could alias.

But if member `t` is present, they should no longer be pointer-interconvertible and code for the non-aliased case should be generated. But in both cases the code is identical except the relative address of member `k`.

The assembler:

```
fn(X const&, int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 2
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        ret
```

As an counter-example

```
template<typename T>
struct X {int k; };

int fn(X<struct A>& x, X<struct B>& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p.k = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

in the above version the generated code assumes no aliasing, but the types are pointer-interconvertible.

```
fn(X<A>&, X<B>&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 2
        add     eax, eax
        ret
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `but the types are pointer-interconvertible.` are they?

Comment: Which types do you mean exactly?

Comment: `X<A>` and `X<B>`

Comment: According to what I know: yes. Therefor it seem strange to me, that the compiler assumes no aliasing here, but not in the first example with member `t`.

Comment: `X<A>` and `X<B>` have as much in common as `double` and `std::string` if that is your misunderstanding

Comment: pointer-interconvertiblity has nothing to do with this.  In `fn(const X& x, int& p)` since `X` contains an `int` the compiler can't assume that `p` is not an alias to `X::k`.  Also,  `X<A>` and `X<B>` are not pointer-interconvertible.  Template specializations are unique types.  Just look at `vector<bool>`.

Comment: The generated assembly for any given compiler is *irrelevant*. All that matters is whether or not the code has defined behaviour according to the standard and the abstract machine that C++ programs execute in. What code is used to *manifest* that behaviour is immaterial/irrelevant. And if the code contains undefined behaviour, *anything* is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
int fn(const X& x, int& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

`X::k` is `int`,`p` is a reference to `int`. `p` can be a reference to `x.k`.

On the other hand, here:

```
int fn(X<struct A>& x, X<struct B>& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p.k = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

`X<struct A>` and `X<struct B>` are distinct types. There is no way to have `x` and `p` or parts of it refer to the same object.

> But what if k is private and X has operator int() const returning k ?

Then nothing changes. Sloppy speaking, you need a reference/pointer to get potential aliasing. For example

```
struct G {};
struct H { G* g; }

void foo(G* a,H b);
```

Here `b.g` and `a` can point to the same `G` (note that this is the case no matter if `b` is passed by value, reference or pointer). In your example...

```
template<typename T>
struct X {int k; };
int fn(X<struct A>& x, X<struct B>& p)
```

.. the only references are `x` and `p`. They refer to objects of different types, aka different objects.

Comment: But what if `k` is private and  `X` has `operator int() const` returning `k` ? see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3cA86

Comment: @wimalopaan then nothing changes. Give me a sec I'll add an example

Comment: @wimalopaan I dont know how to explain better. Why do you think adding a `operator int() const` would change something?

Comment: Because it is impossible that `p` is a reference to the private member `k` of `X`.

Comment: @wimalopaan p also cannot be a reference to x.k when it is public

Comment: Sure it can! `int g() {
    X x;

    fn(x, x.k);
}`

Comment: @wimalopaan sorry I was confusing the examples. Anyhow, making a member private is no fool proof protection against access, if you are foolish enough you can get a reference to a private member ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here

```cpp
int fn(const X& x, int& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

the compiler has to assume that `p` may be a reference to `x.k`. Both `p` and `x.k` are lvalues of type `int`. Thus, they may be aliasing each other. Whether `X` is pointer-interconvertible with an `int` or not does not change the fact that `p` may be a reference to `x.k`.

Here

```cpp
int fn(X<struct A>& x, X<struct B>& p) {
    int i = x.k;
    p.k = 2;
    return i + x.k;
}
```

on the other hand, `X<struct A>` and `X<struct B>` are completely unrelated types. `x` and `p` cannot be references to the same object. Thus, `x.k` and `p.k` cannot denote the same subobject. The fact that `X<struct A>` as well as `X<struct B>` are both pointer-interconvertible with an `int` is, again, irrelevant…

Comment: i realized I wrote almost exact same answer, just not as nice as yours ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 well, thank you. have an upvote anyways… :D

Comment: But what if k is private and X has operator int() const returning k ? See :https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3cA86

Comment: @wimalopaan what would that change?

Comment: `int& p` can't reference `x.k`.

Comment: @wimalopaan well, if the compiler can prove that that's the case, it can, of course, take advantage of that information. In general, a compiler is *allowed* to optimize the generated machine code under the as-if rule. A compiler is not required to perform this optimization, however. Compilers are generally pretty conservative when it comes to taking advantage of strict aliasing because too much code depends on all sorts of technically undefined behavior just doing what the programmer expected anyways rather than keeping to the bare minimum of what behavior the standard actually guarantees…

Comment: Well, what UB-way could you imagine, so that the compilers pessimizes in that way.

Comment: @wimalopaan trickery with `offsetof` or member pointers, for example. People like to treat objects as just a bunch of bytes they can do with whatever they want. Some people even like to just `#define private public` in the one or other translation unit every once in a while…

Comment: I'm not a compiler engineer, but I would imagine that it just gets really hard to prove that two pointers/references do not alias in general. So I would guess that compilers just don't bother to go through the trouble of taking into account accessibility of members in their alias analysis since there is not all that much to gain from that except a huge potential for introducing a lot of bugs of arguably the worst kind. Consider all the possibilities in which some piece of code somewhere outside the current translation unit could somehow end up able to access the member in question again…